# Calling a method from a separate class file in Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

Building a simple Rock Paper Scissors GUI game for a class project in Java.

Trying to go with an MVC methodology, I moved the code in `resultsGUI()` below from my "Controller" class to my "View" class.

I tried creating an instance of the View class in the Controller class and calling the method like this: `view.resultsGUI();` but that threw exception error in my compiler.

How can I call the `resultsGUI` method which resides in my View class to perform at the bottom of the `chooseWinner()` method (also below) as the code did when it was part of `chooseWinner()`?

I'm a novice and appreciate the help.

chooseWinner method below:

```
    public static void chooseWinner(int x) {
    playerChoice = x;

    String winningCombo = "" + Math.min(compChoice, playerChoice)
            + Math.max(compChoice, playerChoice);

    switch (Integer.parseInt(winningCombo)) {
        case 1:
            text = "Paper wins!";
            if (playerChoice == 2) {
                playerWon = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            text = "Rock wins!";
            if (playerChoice == 1) {
                playerWon = 1;
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            text = "Scissors wins!";
            if (playerChoice == 3) {
                playerWon = 1;
            }
            break;

    }

    if (playerWon == 1) {
        text1 = "Congrats, you win!";
        playerWon = 0;
        win = win + 1;
        total = total + 1;
    } else if (playerWon == 2) {
        text1 = "It's a tie!";
        playerWon = 0;
    } else {
        text1 = "Computer wins!";
        total = total + 1;
    }




}
```

resultsGUI method below:
        public void resultsGUI() {
        JFrame rFrame = new JFrame("Match Results");
        Container panel = rFrame.getContentPane();
        panel.setLayout(null);

```
    JLabel l0 = new JLabel(controller.text1 + controller.text);
    l0.setBounds(75, 10, 300, 35);
    panel.add(l0);


    //show the result in a new splash screen

    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Human's Choice");
    l1.setBounds(40, 35, 150, 35);
    panel.add(l1);

    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("Computer's Choice");
    l2.setBounds(215, 35, 150, 35);
    panel.add(l2);

    JLabel l3 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/image/" + (controller.playerChoice - 1) + ".jpg"));
    l3.setBounds(10, 100, 170, 60);
    panel.add(l3);

    JLabel l4 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/image/" + (controller.compChoice - 1) + ".jpg"));
    l4.setBounds(200, 100, 170, 60);
    panel.add(l4);

    JLabel l5 = new JLabel("Win/Loss rate: " + controller.win + "/" + controller.total);
    l5.setBounds(125, 25, 150, 350);
    panel.add(l5);

    JLabel l6 = new JLabel("Tie: " + controller.tie);
    l6.setBounds(125, 30, 125, 370);
    panel.add(l6);

    rFrame.setSize(400, 270);
    rFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Control should have an instance of the View and the Model, and not just *any* View and Model instance, but rather the active currently visualized View and the currently used Model. Something like this could be in your class with the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  View view = new View();
  Model model = new Model();
  Control control = new Control(view, model);

  // start the GUI up
}
```

In your Control class you would use the constructor parameters to set class fields:

```
public class Control {
  private View view;
  private Model model;

  public Control(View view, Model model) {
    this.view = view;
    this.model = model;
  }

  // now your control can call model and view methods.
  // ....
}
```

Comment: @phamousphil: you're welcome! Thanks for getting back to us with your resolution!

Answer (score 0):

you need to compose your `Game` class with the other classes.  So you get this:

```
class Game  
{     
    View view = new View();  
    public void foo()  
    {  
        view.getResults();
    }    
}
```

If you don't want to instantiate the `View` class, you can mark the `getResults` function as static and reference it like this:

```
View.getResults()
```